# Error when adding typedef in header

Tags: c++, dictionary, header-files, typedef

I'm new to C++, and I'm learning from Accelerated C++ (for anyone with the book, I'm trying to run the program described in §7.4)

The program I'm looking at uses some typedefs - I gather that if I add these to a header file, any source file which includes that header will be able to use the typedefs too.

My header is:

```
#ifndef READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
#define READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED

typedef std::vector<std::string> Rule;
typedef std::vector<Rule> Rule_collection;
typedef std::map<std::string, Rule_collection> Grammar;

Grammar read_grammar(std::istream& in);

#endif // READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
```

This is giving me the error `error: 'map' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`

If I change the third typedef to `typedef std::vector<Rule_collection> Grammar;` (not that I want this, just for example) it builds with no errors.

Any idea what the problem is? I have no idea whether I'm doing something trivial the wrong way, or whether the whole approach is incorrect

Comment: You need to `#include<map>` `<vector>` and `<string>` edit: and `<iosfwd>`

Comment: @rbennett485 I am sure map is a spy!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that these are some of the silliest typedefs I've ever seen.

Comment: @Puppy yeah I think it's one of those 'contrived, making a point' type examples rather than a genuine application

Comment: @rbennett485 I would not say that these are the sillest typedefs. It is an attempt to make the abstraction Grammar independent of its realization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says it cannot find `map` in namespace `std`. You need to include it so that the compiler can find it. Similarly, you'll need to include headers for `std::vector` `std::string` and `std::istream`:

```
#ifndef READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
#define READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Rule;
typedef std::vector<Rule> Rule_collection;
typedef std::map<std::string, Rule_collection> Grammar;

Grammar read_grammar(std::istream& in);

#endif // READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
```

If you feel courageous, you might also want to read about forward declarations - their usage, pros and cons, but I doubt it's needed in this particular case.

Comment: This makes good sense. Any idea why it was only giving an error for the missing `#include <map>` though, and not for the missing `#include <vector>`?

Comment: You probably already included them somewhere else, and the actual error is thrown by the `.cpp` file which includes this header.

Comment: @rbennett485, Likely something you included before this header included the others.

Comment: @rbennett485 Because you're including the missing headers (except `<map>`) either directly or indirectly in the files where you're including this header.

Answer (score 3):

You must include the header files, if you don't have them included then how is your program going to use it?

```
#ifndef READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
#define READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED

#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

typedef std::vector<std::string> Rule;
typedef std::vector<Rule> Rule_collection;
typedef std::map<std::string, Rule_collection> Grammar;

Grammar read_grammar(std::istream& in);

#endif // READ_GRAMMAR_H_INCLUDED
```